TensorFlow does not detect GPU 2024
I'm using an RTX 3050 Laptop GPU with the latest driver update:
NVIDIA-SMI 555.99
Driver Version: 555.99
CUDA Version: 12.5
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Apr_17_19:36:51_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.5, V12.5.40
Build cuda_12.5.r12.5/compiler.34177558_0
I'm using Python 3.11 and Windows 11
I'm using cuDNN version 8.9.7
Since 2019, TensorFlow no longer uses tensorflow-gpu but instead integrates GPU support within tensorflow. Most questions regarding TensorFlow not detecting the GPU were asked before 2021, so I want to inquire about the current version.
=========================================================
The "tensorflow-gpu" package has been removed!
  Please install "tensorflow" instead.

  Other than the name, the two packages have been identical
  since TensorFlow 2.1, or roughly since Sep 2019. For more
  information, see: pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu

=========================================================
I have installed cuDNN in the correct location and set the PATH properly (or so I believe):
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\libnvvp
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\extras\CUPTI\lib64
I have tried using Visual Studio Code and Anaconda, but the GPU is still not detected. I have also installed the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

I hope my issue is resolved soon because I want to run TensorFlow with the GPU on this laptop.

Please read the release notes for Tensorflow on Windows. There is no more native GPU support on Windows official  builds after Tensorflow 2.11

I have already changed it to the CUDA toolkit according to TensorFlow's req:
tensorflow-2.11.0, Python 3.7-3.10, Compiler GCC 9.3.1,Build tools Bazel 5.3.0, cuDNN 8.1, CUDA 11.2
But the problem is I cannot perform pip install tensorflow==2.11.0
I have read many articles about this, but I couldn't find the Windows req for CUDA. Can you provide a reference?
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0

Tensorflow 2.10 is actually the last with GPU support on native Windows. Like I said, read the release notes carefully

Its probably much easier if you just use WSL for tensorflow GPU support on Windows.

please give me the installation instructions, I've been trying to install it for hours. I've installed WSL multiple times but nvcc doesn't appear. I've also tried version 2.11, but still failed

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2

thank you everyone, i have successfully done it in anaconda and wsl
